# How to redirect pages via htaccess when URL appears after the file extension?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, redirect, duplicate-content

I already have htaccess redirection for all bad requests to custom/default 404 page:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

But still the site can be accessed like:
`http://www.domain.com/index.html/http:/domain.com`

It cause duplicate content issue and duplicate SEO tag issues.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> http://www.example.com/index.html/http:/example.com
>                                  |----------------|
>                                     ^ path-info ^
> ```

This additional URL-path starting with a slash that follows the end of a URL that maps to a physical file is called "additional pathname information" (accessible in JavaScript through the `Location.pathname` property, or in PHP through the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` superglobal). Unless explicitly stated, whether it is accepted or not (on the server) is controlled by the handler for the request. However, it can be explicitly enabled/disabled with the `AcceptPathInfo` directive in your `.htaccess` file:

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

With it `Off`, then URLs that contain *path-info* will trigger a 404.

See also:

- [How does Apache handle index.php/some_text webpage requests? It returns http status 200 instead of expected 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70369041/how-does-apache-handle-index-php-some-text-webpage-requests-it-returns-http-sta)
- [Why apache take files php like folders or virtual url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63121247/why-apache-take-files-php-like-folders-or-virtual-url)