# Why does Apache treat PHP files like folders or virtual URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a site with the URL `https://example.com/file.php`. I don't use URL friendly, frameworks, etc. But I see that google take duplicate content from my website, but with URL that not exist like:

```
https://example.com/file.php/file2.php
https://example.com/file.php/file3.php
https://example.com/file.php/file3.php/hihi/other/other2.php   (status 200)
```

But that URLs do not exist. In both cases show me the content from `file.php`. I delete my `.htaccess` because I think I have some bad rule, but is not that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Quentin has already pointed out - this is the default for PHP. Or, more specifically, the Apache handler that processes PHP, allows *path-info* (additional pathname information on the URL) by default. Plain `text/html` files do not allow path-info, unless explicitly enabled.

For example, given the following URL:

```
https://example.com/file.php/<anything>
```

Where `file.php` is a physical file on the filesystem, then `/<anything>` is the additional pathname information. And is available to PHP through the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable.

However, you can disable this in `.htaccess` with the `AcceptPathInfo` directive:

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

Now any URL that contains *path-info* will trigger a 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 1):

That the default behaviour for PHP. It's useful when implementing [the Front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) as you can inspect the full path through the `$_SERVER` superglobal.

Make use of the [`canonical` link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types) to avoid duplicate content in search engines.