# URLs containing /index.php/ as subdirectory show content of index.php

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a clean installation of Apache+PHP (latest) on CentOS 8 with no customization on `php.ini` nor `.htaccess` files. For some reason when I open URLs like:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php/xxxx/flkjfd.jpg
https://www.example.com/index.php/SLkfjLj/
https://www.example.com/index.php/9kf944.994
```

They always show the content of the `index.php` file located at the root. If I remove that file, than the URLs above show 404 error. How can this happen? I have no directory "index.php"! I have only a file "index.php" with some random string... How can I prevent this?

Isnt this weird? Or is this expected?

Comment: What does your .htaccess file look like?

Comment: If you try navigating to some non-existent URL - without deleting index.php - do you get a 404 or redirected to index?

Comment: I have no .htaccess file. I didnt understand the "non-existent URL". I have absolutely no other file in my server (other than the index.php file) and any path that I use in the URL it opens the index.php file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Apache handle index.php/some\_text webpage requests? It returns http status 200 instead of expected 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70369041/how-does-apache-handle-index-php-some-text-webpage-requests-it-returns-http-sta)

Comment: Yes, this is expected (default) behaviour. The part after a valid _file_ (eg. `/xxxx/flkjfd.jpg`) is called "path-info". See the above question which explains more and how to prevent this.